# Configuring eclipse, maven and archiva

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, archiva

I'm trying to configure Apache Archiva, Maven and Spring Tool Suite.
I have installed Apache Archiva in a Debian Server. At this moment it's running and I can access it using the webapp.

I have installed Maven3, and Spring Tool Suite but I can't compile the project. It's my first time setting up a repository and configuring maven for that.

Basically I want a way to make versions and "store" my snapshots and releases.

On my settings.xml I have the following:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>archiva.central</id>
      <url>http://MY_IP_ADDRESS:MY_PORT/archiva/repository/internal</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>


</settings>
```

Than I created a Maven Project with the following .pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pt.XX.YYY</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project-name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://XXXX@bitbucket.org/XXXX/my-project-name.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://XXXX@bitbucket.org/XXXX/my-project-name.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/XXXX/my-project-name</url>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshots Repo</name>
            <url>http://MY_IP_ADDRESS:MY_PORT/archiva/repository/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>internal</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <url>http://MY_IP_ADDRESS:MY_PORT/archiva/repository/internal</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${javaVersion}</source>
                        <target>${javaVersion}</target>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <goals>deploy</goals>
                    </configuration>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>

</project>
```

Unfortunately STS says the following:

"Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\XXXX.m2\repository), archiva.central (http://MY_IP_ADDRESS:MY_PORT/archiva/repository/internal)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository"